# Using Include? in Celerity Screen Scraping Script

Tags: include, screen-scraping, celerity

I am using to Celerity to screen scrape a web page and I'm attempting to scrape all of the text elements within a particular div class.  The following line of code I'm using is throwing the following error: wrong argument type String (expected Module) (TypeError)

Code: `puts browser.text if browser.frame(:id, 'bottomframe').div.class.include? 'ClassName'`

Can anyone tell me what this error means or more importantly how to fix my line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further review of the Celerity documentation has provided a solution to my question.

Celerity provides the ability to use Regular Expressions to specify what you would like to find/match on the particular web page.  For example: browser.link(:text, /ish/) means the first  element that matches the regular expression /ish/.

Thanks